# Pushing to local gitosis server asks for password

Tags: ubuntu, git

I've installed gitosis onto my server, but seeing as I'm developing on the server, I'd like to be able to push to gitosis, so I can work from macmini as well.  The server is called `workwork` and the gitosis-admin has the daniel@workwork.pub file generated from the server, and has this in gitosis.conf:

```
[group testproject]
writable = testproject
members = daniel@workwork
```

And that successfully has been pushed to the server.

```
rails new testproject
cd testproject/
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "init commit"
git remote add origin gitosis@workwork:testproject.git
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

The last command gives this: `gitosis@workwork's password:`  gitosis doesn't have a password, and pushing a new project from my macmini just does the correct git pushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitosis has known unfixed bugs in its installation method that prevent it from working without manual intervention. You should not use it and instead switch to [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). Additionally gitosis is unmaintained and deprecated, further reasons to switch to [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

Comment: I'll have a look into gitolite, but I'd like to know why its not working.  Can you suggest a reason why its failing to "remote" to itself?

Comment: The `post-receive` hook does not get set to executable so it does not update `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.